# How to generate the total time required for the entire test plan in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have an aggregate report:

[image]

Do I have to add another listener or add anything else to the testplan?
For ex: consider the above snapshot:
I'm running 9002 samples, **I just need to know the total time required for all the 9002 samples?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 9002 Samples are played in a sequence by only 1 user, just use a TransactionController that will contain your HTTP Request and you will have this.

If 9002 samples are played by different users then you can export the CSV file that contains the test results and use Excel to sum up the elapsed column.

To generate a CSV file, run test in NON GUI Mode using:

> jmeter -n -l results.csv -t test.jmx